# Open Windows Store with specific app using WinAPI (C++)

Tags: windows-store-apps

The Microsoft [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-store-app) says I need to use ms-windows-store URI scheme. Tried this:

```
std::wstring urlStore = L"ms-windows-store://pdp/?PFN=Microsoft.Office.OneNote_8wekyb3d8bbwe";
::ShellExecute(GetActiveWindow(), L"open", urlStore.c_str(), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Result: opens the store app on its last page, not on the OneNote page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it (using API monitor on another app that is able to do that).

```
std::wstring urlStore = StringHelpers::format(L"ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=%s", m_strPackageFamilyName);
::ShellExecute(GetActiveWindow(), L"open", urlStore.c_str(), L"", L"", SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```